# Linux function calls at certain intervals

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I need to be able to call certain functions at different intervals on Linux using C/C++. What is the best method to do this? For instance I want to call a() at 100hz and b() at 10hz and c() at 1hz.

Comment: Have you bothered to google "timers on linux"?

Comment: Some old linux kernels might not be able to call a function at 100Hz reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [settimer](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/setitimer/) repeatedly to schedule the next function call which has the closest deadline.

Comment: I realize that, is there anyway to setup at the start of the program to call certain functions at different intervals?

Comment: The intervals are even ratios... so every 10 calls of 100hz is 10hz, every 100 is 1 hz.  One timer should be sufficient, provided the system can reliably provide timers at the desired resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Posix timers, i.e. [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and [timer_settime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html). Then you want to set a signal handler using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). Be aware that signal handler functions are only allowed to call a very restricted set of functions (only the *async-signal-safe* functions, but even not `fprintf` or `malloc`!), see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and consider simply setting a `volatile sigatomic_t` variable in your signal handler (and test it appropriately outside).

You might instead having some event loop (e.g. [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), or making your own one with a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc...). If you are coding a graphical application (using e.g. Qt or Gtk) you already have an event loop, so use it (and you also have timers provided by the graphical toolkit or the event loop functions).

You may also want to look at [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and friends (and use that fle descriptor in your event loop or `poll(2)` call).

Reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) should help.

<sup>PS. Getting a reliable 100Hz (or slighly higher) timer frequency might be difficult with old kernels and old machines. You may want `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y` and `CONFIG_TIMERFD=y` and `CONFIG_HPET_TIMER=y` and `CONFIG_HZ_1000=y` in the `.config` fle of your recent kernel.</sup>